# Apple LLVM 6.0 Error: clang failed with exit code -1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

I created my app on my MacBook Air and kept working with it there which was fine. Then I started working with a colleague who used another Mac (of course). Anyway, we share our Xcode project via Dropbox (we are just switching to BitBucket, don't worry ;) ), when he tried to open the project on his Mac there was a `Apple LLVM 6.0 Error` with the following error while on my computer the same project runs perfectly:

> **clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/linus/Dropbox/Apps/My App/Projekt/My App/SlideMenu/SlideMenu-Prefix.pch'
>   clang: error: no input files**
>
> **Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1**

The last lines of the error seem most important to me which is why I listed them here.

I do know this question was asked several times now but there was never a useful answer which worked for me. I tried to disable the `Foundation Assertions` as it said in another answer on this topic but that did not work. Also I restarted & even reinstalled Xcode and all files are existing, none should be missing.

I am running Xcode 6.0.1 and Mac OS X 10.10. I hope someone can answer this, I'm kind of desperate now...

Comment: see this url it solve ur problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181673/command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcodedefault-xctoo/24184503#24184503

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Hey I just ran into the same problem. Basically I deleted my tests target. I found this:

[Errors When Compiling iOS 8, Xcode 6.0.1](http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=F42D8239A330C321132944A&currentPage=3)

Which basically says that:

> Click on the name of your project on the list of files/folders on the
>   left in Xcode (at the very top of the list). Look at the "Targets"
>   section on the left-hand side of the window to the right. Likely,
>   there's two listed with the second being a "test" item. Right-click on
>   that item and select "delete". Then try to run the project again. See
>   screenshot below for a visual cue.

And a picture to help you out:

[image: Screenshot]
Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Also in the `tests` target, I actually found that I didn't necessarily need to delete it, there was a broken path, just fixing it makes it all work again.

Comment: Any idea how to fix this if you don't have a test target?

Answer (score 4):

1. Make new file: ⌘cmd+N
2. iOS/Mac > Other > PCH File > YourProject-Prefix.pch.
3. Project > Build Settings > Search: "Prefix Header".
4. Under "Apple LLVM 6.0" you will get the Prefix Header key
5. Type in: "YourProjectName/YourProject-Prefix.pch"
6. Clean project: ⌘cmd+⇧shift+K
7. Build project: ⌘cmd+B

Answer (score 4):

Solved this by going to my project settings and changing the deployment target. The deployment target was originally at 7.0. When i changed it from iOS 8.0 -> 9.1 it works fine and there is no error.

[image]

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to delete the overall build settings. Just change the Library Search Paths, here are the steps:

1. Click on your project name (very top of the navigator)
2. Click on your project target
3. Click the tab `Build Settings`
4. Search for `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS`
5. Change its value to `$(inherited)` flag.

Here you go!

Or else you can always remove the build setting at all! Cheers!

Comment: How to remove build settings?

Comment: @JosephSelvaraj Check the selected answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26812114/4396941

Answer (score 2):

One of the simple things I did I went into "Build Options" and changed the property for `Enable Bitcode` from `yes` to `no`

This fixed my issue.

[Screenshot of Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b55l2.png)

Answer (score 1):

clang can't locate your precompiled header file.  Have you checked whether there is a file named SlideMenu-Prefix.pch in /Users/linus/Dropbox/Apps/My App/Projekt/My App/ ?  The path to the precompiled header file is specified by the "Prefix Header" build setting for your target.

Answer (score 0):

Try,
   In Xcode project settings,
     Targets-> Tests section-> Build Settings->Linking  remove all linkig

OR   Remove Tests Section as a whole.

Build again and Its done!!