# Archive apple LLVM 6.0 error could not read profile

Tags: ios, xcode

When in device test it's ok. But when I want to archive, xcode give the error like this.

error: Could not read profile: No such file or directory

it is the errors

```
CompileC /Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/jinbi.build/Release-iphoneos/jinbi.build/Objects-normal/armv7/UIColor+Extension.o jinbi/Views/NavigationMenuView/UIColor+Extension.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /wikimo/project/iyoo-ios-app
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -fprofile-instr-use=/wikimo/project/iyoo-ios-app/OptimizationProfiles/jinbi.profdata -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -iquote /Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/jinbi.build/Release-iphoneos/jinbi.build/哎呦瘦了-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/jinbi.build/Release-iphoneos/jinbi.build/哎呦瘦了-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/jinbi.build/Release-iphoneos/jinbi.build/哎呦瘦了-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/jinbi.build/Release-iphoneos/jinbi.build/哎呦瘦了-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/jinbi.build/Release-iphoneos/jinbi.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/jinbi.build/Release-iphoneos/jinbi.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -include /Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/PrecompiledHeaders/jinbi-Prefix-gdlmasukgjdlutbqrcfgpdbwoxhr/jinbi-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/jinbi.build/Release-iphoneos/jinbi.build/Objects-normal/armv7/UIColor+Extension.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/jinbi.build/Release-iphoneos/jinbi.build/Objects-normal/armv7/UIColor+Extension.dia -c /wikimo/project/iyoo-ios-app/jinbi/Views/NavigationMenuView/UIColor+Extension.m -o /Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/jinbi.build/Release-iphoneos/jinbi.build/Objects-normal/armv7/UIColor+Extension.o
```

because the

```
/Users/wikimo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jinbi-anvflcahmvfrbchckuahzoashzvm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/jinbi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/jinbi.build/Release-iphoneos/jinbi.build/Objects-normal/armv7/UIColor+Extension.o
```

can not generate. How can I generate?

Targets -> Valid Architectures has already added armv7 architecture

Comment: now I have this problem too -  I can not fix it. Tried it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772504/apple-llvm-6-0-error-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1) but to no avail(result).

Answer (score 16):

Here is the solution if any one want.....

Go to `Project -> Build Setting -> Apple LLVM 6.0-code generation`

and clear `Optimization Profile File`

Clean Your project.....Build your project and archive your project....and you are done....

Comment: I tried that and it got rid of the error in the title, but now I just have one error - and it says INTERNAL ERROR. PLEASE FILE A BUG AT BUGREPORT.APPLE.COM blah blah...   not sure if it is related to deleting the Optimization Profile File or not. And now I am stumped. I am a newbie at iOS development. I see I am due to update XCode from 7.1 to 7.1.1. So it's trying to update now. I hope that fixes it.  :-(

Comment: This morning I found that the update to XCode 7.1.1 cleared up my bug issue reported in my last comment above. The bug is gone and now my project runs fine.

Answer (score 4):

Endorsing [El Captain][1] response using LLVM 8.0:

1. Go to Project → Build Setting → `Apple LLVM 8.0-code generation`
2. Clear the `Optimization Profile File`
3. Clean project
4. Build project

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow this steps:

- Clean your project
- Remove derived data
- Go to Targets -> Valid Architectures & add armv7 architecture
- Build & Run your project

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: hi,cyberlobe,Valid Architectures has already added the armv7 architecture, and in device test is ok , but archive is errors,because the "armv7/UIColor+Extension.o " can't generate, but i don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Select App targets. Right click on the test target and delete it. 
Clean your project and Run.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Project → Build Setting → **Search "OptimizationProfiles"**
2. Clear the Optimization Profile File
3. Clean project (Command + K)
4. Build project (Command + B)