# Apple LLVM 6.1 Error Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i'm working on a simple sample to work with parse.com but i had a problem in xCode, i've added all the requested libraries to my project but still didn't solve .

**Apple LLVM 6.1:**

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Node-B/Desktop/21:6:2015/RecipeAppParseTemplate/CustomTable/CustomTable-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
```

By deleting the test file it gives another error which the reference shown below didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Have you checked whether the "missing" file is there or not? Also have a look at my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772504/apple-llvm-6-0-error-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1

Comment: i don't know what this is means 'CustomTable-Prefix.pch' ? how could it be missing !

Comment: ive tried your solution but its giving me this error at runtime : `The application could not be verified.`

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to delete the test file as mentioned here : 
[Apple LLVM 6.0 Error: clang failed with exit code -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772504/apple-llvm-6-0-error-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Due to that it gives me another error which is `The Application couldn't be verified` from Xcode at Runtime when i run it on my iPhone , and thats why because the app was installed already, so I've delete it and run the project from xCode and it works well.