# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)3

Tags: objective-c, xcode7

I am getting the following error whenever I am making the new project.
On changing the Enable Bit Code to No the error is going.

But once I design my main story board i.e. add table view controller and navigation controller to main story board above error is coming again.

I am posting screen shots of the error and my build settings.[image]

Comment: Check out the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26772504/3397217

Comment: It says you have a duplicated symbol called storedObject in `HomeTableViewController` and `StoreDetailTableViewController`.. can you tell us what is defined as storedObject inside those 2 view controllers?

Comment: My storeObject is static and  now I am now giving different names to these objects in each file

Answer (score 0):

I found [this Apple Support thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6724537?start=0&tstart=0) that might help, here is what the answer says:

> I'm guessing it was because you have duplicate symbols. It is probably
>   something defined in a header file that should be in a source file

So here are several things that might be causing the issue:

- You are importing a `.m` file, only import `.h` files
- If you have an `@implementation` in a header file, those only go in the implementation file.
- You might have a `.m` file that is included twice. Leave only one file reference.

[image]

You would be able to see them in the Build Phases, see image

- There might be a declaration above the `@Interface` in the `.h` file, put it in the `@Interface`
- Declaring a constant or variable in different `.h` files with the same name.
- Changing 'No Common Blocks' from Yes to No might help (under Targets->Build Settings->Apple LLVM - Code Generation)
- This could happen also when you have the same `@interface` in different files with different implementations. For example you have a Player class, in the `Player.h/m` files and you have a Match class (`Match.h/m`), and a match is between two player, but not the aforementioned Player.

Player.h

```
@interface Player : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger _id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* lastName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* username;
@end
```

Match.h

```
@class Player

@interface Match : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) Player* player1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Player* player2;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger matchId;
@end

@interface Player : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* nickName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* point;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* lastMove;
@end
```

In this case the the compiler see two different Player class implementation. You need to refactor the Player class in the `Match.h` file to MatchPlayer.