# How to Resolve Xcode Linker Warnings For Tests Target in App

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-warning

The solution offered in [Apple LLVM 6.0 Error: clang failed with exit code -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772504/apple-llvm-6-0-error-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1) may work to resolve this problem, but as I stated at the end of my problem statement is that I did not want to remove the Tests target unless that is the only solution. So, is there another solution?

When trying to build a new app in Xcode, I am getting a ton of linker warnings. The warnings are related to a target that was automatically created called Tests. The expanded view of some of the warnings look like the following:

```
Ld /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_App-ahfusfuifhsybmalxaykbmfrhylc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/My\ AppTests.xctest/My\ AppTests normal arm64
cd "/Users/me/iPhone Apps/myProducts/My App"
. . .
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
```

and

```
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_App-ahfusfuifhsybmalxaykbmfrhylc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/My\ AppTests.xctest.dSYM /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_App-ahfusfuifhsybmalxaykbmfrhylc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/My\ AppTests.xctest/My\ AppTests
cd "/Users/me/iPhone Apps/myProducts/My App"
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_App-ahfusfuifhsybmalxaykbmfrhylc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/My\ AppTests.xctest/My\ AppTests -o /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_App-ahfusfuifhsybmalxaykbmfrhylc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/My\ AppTests.xctest.dSYM

while processing /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_App-ahfusfuifhsybmalxaykbmfrhylc/Build/Intermediates/My App.build/Debug-iphoneos/My AppTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/My_AppTests.o:
warning: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/3K6537SSXYD4O/UIKit-2LM3EQU7VVY4O.pcm: No such file or directory
...
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)XCTestCase
...
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)_XCTestCaseInterruptionException
```

What can I do to eliminate these warnings? Since I don't really understand how to use test cases yet, I'd rather not delete the target (but if that is the only option, I will).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apple LLVM 6.0 Error: clang failed with exit code -1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772504/apple-llvm-6-0-error-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Comment: @LinusG. Your solution may work to resolve my problem, but as I stated at the end of my problem statement, I'd rather not remove the Tests target unless that is the only solution. So, is there another solution?

Comment: Yeah I know but there were a couple of other answers that suggested a way w/o having to delete the targets.

Comment: @LinusG. ok, you're right. Thanks. Setting the Build Settings Library_Search_Path to $(inherited) removes the warnings. Hopefully that doesn't break something else in the future.

Comment: Can't tell, happy to help though.

Comment: Oh and make sure to give some upvotes if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

For these messages:

```
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs) xXX
```

The problem happens when you have a Xcode 6 project updated to 7. The short answer is to change the Debug Information Format to "DWARF", on the target, for the Debug configuration only.

- Go to Build Settings and search for Debug Information Format
- Change the Debug setting from "DWARF with dSYM File" to "DWARF"
- Leave the Release setting at "DWARF with dSYM File"

This is safe because you don't need  dSYM files for Debug builds