# GenerateDSYMFile - myApp.app.dSYM : Warning AppRight.framework iWatcher-Prefix.pch.pch : No such file or directory

Tags: objective-c

Hello I have this warning in my app.
I try a few question here but I still have this warning.

My Xcode Version 7.3.1 .

[How to Resolve Xcode Linker Warnings For Tests Target in App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754326/how-to-resolve-xcode-linker-warnings-for-tests-target-in-app)

[Why isn't ProjectName-Prefix.pch created automatically in Xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6)

```
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-fmkhzdegfwstnraidtlamfmzobuq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.app.dSYM /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-fmkhzdegfwstnraidtlamfmzobuq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.app myApp
cd /Users/myName/Desktop/myApp
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-fmkhzdegfwstnraidtlamfmzobuq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.app/myApp -o /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-fmkhzdegfwstnraidtlamfmzobuq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.app.dSYM

while processing /Users/myName/Desktop/myApp/AppRight.framework/AppRight(GrNativeCrashEvent.o):
warning: /Users/gryphonet/workspace/ios/iWatcher/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/iWatcher-Prefix-clslxlldlvbjdmgkugmxtoospkbr/iWatcher-Prefix.pch.pch: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You can add the .pch file yourself. This is normal to do this.

Comment: Dominic ,I add but still have this warning.

Comment: if the .pch file is listed in your project, make sure that it isn't associated with any targets since the compiler will do this for you. Also make sure that you have it in your build settings in the section (Prefix Header).

Comment: Dominic : I add "iWatcher-Prefix.pch.pch" file to my project , in precompile prefix header is YES , and in prefix header "$(PRODUCT_DIR)/Users/ranenoch/Desktop/Loco/iWatcher-Prefix.pch.pch" , I add this but still have this warning.

Comment: Too many .pch .... iWatcher-Prefix.pch.pch should be iWatcher-Prefix.pch

Comment: I know , but before i add that file , I have this warning and In this warning they say - warning: /Users/gryphonet/workspace/ios/iWatcher/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/iWatcher-Prefix-clslxlldlvbjdmgkugmxtoospkbr/iWatcher-Prefix.pch.pch: No such file or directory    - so I add file like they need.

Comment: how can i remove this warning ?